# Practical calculation of polynomial expansions in powers of a linear form $x-r$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

In [The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra: A Visual Approach by
Daniel J. Velleman](https://acdc.amherst.edu/view/octagon:144/CONTENT) there appears the comment

> For example, near the root at $−1$ in Figure 3, the colors have been rotated $180$ degrees, so that red is to the left of the root rather than to the right. This is because when the polynomial $f(z)$ of Figure 3 is **expanded in powers of $z + 1,$** the coefficient of $z + 1$ is a negative real number.)

[image]

$-1$ is a root of multiplicity $1$ of the polynomial

$$z^8-2z^7+2z^6-4z^5+2z^4-2z^3-5z^2+4z-4.$$

*Expanding in powers of* seems to correspond to a [change of variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2665154/521868) - parenthetically, is there a name for this so as to avoid misunderstandings with Taylor expansion? - so that

$$(z + 1) \underbrace{(z^7 - 3 z^6 + 5 z^5 - 9 z^4 + 11 z^3 - 13 z^2 + 8 z - 4)}_{g(z)}$$

leads to a reformulation of $g(z)$ as

$$g(z) = a_0 + a_1 (z +1) + a_2(z +1)^2 + \ldots$$

This is probably nothing one should attempt without professional help, but I can't even seem to figure out how to get it done with Wolfram Alpha...

> How do you go about doing a change of variables as this one?

In this case I would like to see how "the coefficient of $z+1$ is a negative real number" as a measure of success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED TO EXPLAIN WHY TAYLOR EXPANSION WORKS**

You have actually mentioned in your answer what you need: the expansion in powers of $z+1$ of $f(z)$ is nothing more than **Taylor expansion around $-1$**. To do it, you just use that
$$f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^8 \frac{f^{(i)}(-1)}{i!}(z+1)^i.$$

Explicitly, we have
$$f(z)=-54(z+1)+153(z+1)^2-216(z+1)^3+192(z+1)^4-114(z+1)^5+44(z+1)^6-10(z+1)^7+(z+1)^8.$$

You can expand and collect to check that this expression is indeed $f(z)$ (in Matlab you can write *collect(polynomial,z)*)

---

**ADDED:**

Suppose $f(X)=a_nX^n+\ldots +a_1X+a_0$ and you want to write the same polynomial but centered at the number $c$, i.e., as
$$f(X)=b_n(X-c)^n+\ldots+b_1(X-c)+b_0.$$
So, what we want is to find the coefficients $b_i$ from our initial expression for $f$. Observe that $b_0$ is just $f(c)$. This evaluation idea is very convenient; can we apply it to find the other $b_i$?

Well, if we look at $f(X)-b_0$ we see we have a multiple of $X-c$, 
$$f(X)-b_0=(b_n(X-c)^{n-1}+\ldots+b_1)(X-c),$$
and if we divide by $X-c$ we get
$$f_1(X):=\frac{f(X)-b_0}{X-c}=b_n(X-c)^{n-1}+\ldots+b_2(X-c)+b_1,$$
so now we can evaluate $f_1(c)$ to get $b_1$.

As you see, this process of getting $b_i$ from $f_i(X)$ can be continued until we have all the desired coefficients.

But let us see, how does the procedure work? We are getting rid of a constant, and then we are reducing the degree of every $(X-c)^i$ by one. Doesn't this sound like taking the derivative?

If instead of substracting and dividing we just derive, we get instead
$$f^{(1)}(X)=nb_n(X-c)^{n-1}+\ldots+2b_2(X-c)+b_1,$$
$$f^{(2)}(X)=n(n-1)b_n(X-c)^{n-2}+\ldots+3\cdot2(X-c)+2b_2,$$
and so on. We see that an artificial factor of $i!$ appears when we evaluate $f^{(i)}(c)=i!b_i$ to get $b_i$, so we need to divide by it to get 
$$b_i=\frac{f^{(i)}(c)}{i!}.$$

Therefore we have shown (and understood)
$$f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{f^{(i)}(c)}{i!}(X-c)^i.$$

Comment: Thank you, José! This is very helpful. I have 2 follow-up questions: 1. On Wolfram Alpha ((here is the calculation)[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+expansion+at+z%3D-1+of+f(z)%3Dz%5E8-2z%5E7%2B2z%5E6-4z%5E5%2B2z%5E4-2z%5E3-5z%5E2%2B4z-4]) there is a big o term. When and how did you decide to cut the number of terms? If I enter your expression  in Wolfram Alpha I do indeed recover the polynomial in the original question - there is no approximation there...

Comment: And 2. Can you shed some light on this discussion about Taylor series versus change of variables going on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2665182/521868)?

Comment: @shouldn'tbehere I suppose Wolfram Alpha just adds a big-o term by default, as you are asking for a Taylor expansion, so it gives the "error term". But in this case you actually have O(f(x))=0

Comment: Any thoughts on change of variables versus Taylor, or is it the same when it comes to polynomials?

Comment: @shouldn'tbehere I think that what you want to know is **why** the Taylor expansion gives the same answer as the changes of variables. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I'm thinking that your extended answer would work very well for the post linked in my second comment above. I'd be happy to accept it if you wanted to simply copy and paste. In here it is great for background, but there it could actually be *the* answer.

Comment: @shouldn'tbehere I don't know about that; there you asked "what is the point of using the Taylor expansion", and you have a good answer to that: to see the local behaviour, by approximating a polynomial by its greatest local term around a zero. My answer just shows why Taylor expansions works as expected, which is an entirely different question

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,z+1=w\,$ so that $\,z=w-1\,$, then:

$$
 z^7 - 3 z^6 + 5 z^5 - 9 z^4 + 11 z^3 - 13 z^2 + 8 z - 4 \\[5px]
 = (w-1)^7 - 3(w-1)^6 + 5 (w-1)^5-9(w-1)^4+11(w-1)^3-13(w-1)^2+8(w-1) - 4 \\[5px]
 = w^7 - 10 w^6 + 44 w^5 - 114 w^4 + 192 w^3 - 216 w^2 + 153 w - 54 \\[5px]
 = (z+1)^7 - 10 (z+1)^6 + 44 (z+1)^5 - 114 (z+1)^4 + 192 (z+1)^3 - 216 (z+1)^2 + 153 (z+1) - 54
$$

The  calculation can be verified in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E7+-+3+z%5E6+%2B+5+z%5E5+-+9+z%5E4+%2B+11+z%5E3+-+13+z%5E2+%2B+8+z+-+4+where+z%3Dw-1), as shown under "expanded form".

Comment: That simple! Can you shed some light on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2665182/521868) (possibly pseudo-issue)

Comment: @shouldn'tbehere Sorry, but what is the (pseudo-)issue there?

Comment: I don't know if it is a pseudo-issue, or not, but it is in reference to the post linked on my prior comment - Taylor series versus change of variables, or are we talking about the same in different words?

Comment: [Here is the hyperlink to the post in question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2665182/521868). Thank you.

Comment: @shouldn'tbehere My answer uses a "change of variables" only as a means to simplify the calculations. You could textually replace $\,w\,$ with $\,(z+1)\,$ from start to end, and you'd get the same result without using any intermediate variable. The $\,z\,$ in the last expression is the *same* $\,z\,$ as in the first one. The form of the last expression, however, "*happens*" to match the Taylor expansion around $\,z=-1\,$, which can be convenient in some cases, for example when studying the *local* behavior near $\,-1\,$.